# Slow BLOB loading from C# on Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, blob

I have a somewhat unique (and obsolete) mystery for you.

Our software is written in C#, and it connects to Oracle using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library. Our client has a table with some binary data, represented as BLOBs. Each BLOB is relatively small, most often smaller than 1KB.

When we write a query which does not select the BLOB itself, such as "SELECT blob_id, blob_name FROM blob_table WHERE blob_name LIKE 'foo%'", it executes very quickly (the typical query returns anywhere from 1,000 to 10,000 rows). However, when we include the BLOB column, and attempt to read it as a byte[], the query slows down to a crawl. In the worst cases, it can run up to 20 minutes (!).

That's not the entire mystery, though. I tried solving this problem by incrementing InitialLobFetchSize. It turns out that setting the fetch size to 1KB allows the query to run in about 30 seconds. Setting it to somewhere above 500KB *slows down* the query to 30 minutes. What is going on, and how is this possible -- especially given the fact that it downloads, in total, only about 1MB of data ?

In desperation, I wrote a PL/SQL procedure that would run the query; concatenate all the BLOBs into one big temporary BLOB; and then return that BLOB to the client. This approach proved to be the fastest, regardless of fetch size. Again, my question is, why ? Ultimately, how can I make this query execute in reasonable time ?